# Why the value_type/difference_type/pointer/reference of back_insert_iterator/front_insert_iterator/insert_iterator are all void?

Tags: c++, types, iterator, iterator-traits

In my project, I want to split stream into some given type of values, so I implement a template function as

```
template <typename TElem, typename TOutputIter>
TOutputIter SplitSpace(std::istream& IS, TOutputIter result)
{
    TElem elem;
    while (IS >> elem)
    {
        *result = elem;
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I think this is awkward since I have to explicitly given the type of `TElem` when calling it. For example, I have to write:

```
std::vector<int> v;
SplitSpace<int>(std::cin, back_inserter(v));
// I want to it to be   SplitSpace(std::cin, back_inserter(v));
```

I tried to obtain the value type from an (template) iterator and used `std::iterator_traits` as follows:

```
template <typename TOutputIter>
TOutputIter SplitSpace(std::istream& IS, TOutputIter result)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<TOutputIter>::value_type elem;
    while (IS >> elem)
    {
        *result = elem;
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, the above codes do not work for `back_insert_iterator`. I checked the source codes of `back_insert_iterator/front_insert_iterator/insert_iterator` in `std` namespace and found the `value_type/difference_type/pointer/reference` are all `void`.

I would like to know why these types are all `void`, is there any consideration for this? Another question is that is it possible to implement the `SplitSpace` function without explicitly giving the element type when call it? Thanks.

Comment: They are kind of write only iterators, what other type should those typedefs have?

Comment: Not "kind of". They're OutputIterators, i.e. write only and non-repeatable. Still +1 for interesting question

Comment: Definitely weird, there seem to be no reason to mangle the `typedef` when they can be used both to extract *and* insert elements...

Comment: It does not answer your question, but are you familiar with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)? As far as I can tell, it provides exactly the kind of feature you are trying to implement (along with [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)).

Answer (score 7):

`value_type` does not make much sense in the case of OutputIterators, because an output iterator does not give access to any values, and more importantly it can accepts a wide range of value types.

The only requirement for an OutputIterator `it` is that it must supports the expression `*it = o` **where `o` is a value of some type that is in the set of types that are writable to the particular iterator type of i** (§24.2.1). This means that an output iterator can potentially accepts a wide range of types: for instance, its `operator*` can return a proxy object that overloads `operator=` for a variety of types ; what should be `value_type` in this case?

For instance, consider the following output iterator:

```
struct SwallowOutputIterator : 
    public std::iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
    struct proxy // swallows anything
    {
        template <typename T>
        void operator=(const T &) {}
    };

    proxy operator*() 
    {
        return proxy();
    }

    // increment operators
};
```

There is no sensible choice for `value_type` here.

The same reasoning applies to `pointer` and `reference_type`. `difference_type` is not defined because you cannot calculate the distance between two output iterators, as they are single-pass.

N.B.: the standard explicitely states that `insert_iterator` and its siblings must inherits from `iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>`, so this is not a peculiarity of your implementation.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Luc in the comments what you want to do can be easily done with the standard library:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::copy( std::istream_iterator( std::cin )
         , std::istream_iterator()
         , std::back_inserter( v ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are just looking for a way to avoid to specify the `TElem` template param, you can use this approach:

```
template <typename TOutputIter>
TOutputIter SplitSpace(std::istream& IS, TOutputIter result)
{
    typedef typename TOutputIter::container_type::value_type TElem;

    TElem elem;
    while (IS >> elem)
    {
        *result = elem;
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

...of course, depending on which TOutputIter types you pretend to use, you shouldn't use this approach.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you should be able to obtain the `container_type` from the iterator, from which you should be able to obtain a `value_type`. You probably want to specialize for a `pair` at some point. This should answer part two, as for part one; not sure...

Comment: How do you obtain the container type from an iterator (not every output iterator actually has a container type)?

Comment: @ChristianRau, according to this, apparently there should be for the listed iterators: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/front_insert_iterator

Comment: ....doesn't mean that your custom defined iterator called `Bob` will support this functionality... that's your prerogative...

Comment: Well, tell this to the people expecting a generic function that expects an output iterator. Or at least tell it to the OP expecting a generic iterator when reading the word *"iterator"* in the answer.